# limit a excel vba macro to one file

Tags: excel, vba

I'm running a macro that automaticaly protects a worksheet when a cell value changes (with password). This macro runs all the time in all open sheets. This is supposed to be so. But when I have another excel file open, it also protects that sheet with the password. How can I limit my macro to only the file it is in?

Thanks!

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Calculate()
Dim FormulaRange As Range
Dim FormulaRange2 As Range
Dim NotSentMsg As String
Dim MyMsg As String
Dim SentMsg As String
Dim MyLimit As Double

NotSentMsg = "Niet verzonden"
SentMsg = "Verzonden"

'Above the MyLimit value it will run the macro
MyLimit = 0

'Set the range with the Formula that you want to check
Set FormulaRange2 = ActiveSheet.Range("D22")

On Error GoTo EndMacro:
For Each FormulaCell In FormulaRange2.Cells
    With FormulaCell
        If IsNumeric(.Value) = False Then
            MyMsg = "Not numeric"
        Else
            If .Value > MyLimit Then

                MyMsg = SentMsg

                If .Offset(2, 10).Value = NotSentMsg Then
                    Call Mail_with_outlook2
                End If
            Else
                MyMsg = NotSentMsg
            End If
        End If
        Application.EnableEvents = False
ActiveSheet.Unprotect Password:="zou82pam"
        .Offset(2, 10).Value = MyMsg
ActiveSheet.Protect Password:="zou82pam", DrawingObjects:=True, Contents:=True,     
Scenarios:=True
ActiveSheet.EnableSelection = xlUnlockedCells
        Application.EnableEvents = True
    End With
Next FormulaCell

ExitMacro:
Exit Sub

EndMacro:
Application.EnableEvents = True

MsgBox "De onderstaande error is ontstaan. Neem contact op met Wouter van Leeuwen" _
     & vbLf & vbLf & Err.Number _
     & vbLf & Err.Description

End Sub
```

Comment: Just a thought. On a quick look your code looks OK and do _not_ think it would update multiple workbooks (files). So am thinking somehow however you are checking for the change to call your macro it may be firing for all workbooks and calling your (good) macro multiple times?

Comment: I'm sure that many people can help you with the answer; but perhaps it will help you if you accept a few answers to questions that you have received in the past.

Comment: @KimGysen I always clicked the up arrow, thinking this would accept the answer. Just found out otherwise. Thanks for the tip!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a perfect example on how `ActiveSheet` opens up possible bugs and should be avoided as much as possible.

The first thing you need to do is always respect the following object hierarchy:

```
(application) -> workbook -> sheet -> range
```

Translated into VBA this means that it is good practice to ALWAYS write down the entire hierarchy:

```
Thisworkbook.Sheets('sheetname').range("A1")
```

If you use multiple application objects or, more often workbooks, you have control on the objects that you want to manipulate.

Now instead of using:

```
ActiveSheet.Unprotect Password:="zou82pam"
        .Offset(2, 10).Value = MyMsg
ActiveSheet.Protect Password:="zou82pam", DrawingObjects:=True, Contents:=True,     
Scenarios:=True
ActiveSheet.EnableSelection = xlUnlockedCells
        Application.EnableEvents = True
    End With
```

You would have:

```
Thisworkbook.sheets("somesheet").Unprotect Password:="zou82pam"
        .Offset(2, 10).Value = MyMsg
Thisworkbook.sheets("somesheet").Protect Password:="zou82pam", DrawingObjects:=True, Contents:=True,     
Scenarios:=True
Thisworkbook.sheets("somesheet").EnableSelection = xlUnlockedCells
        Application.EnableEvents = True
    End With
```

Now in case you need to loop through multiple sheets, you can always use the sheet index instead of sheet name. For example:

```
Dim iCnt as integer

for iCnt = 1 to 10
    Thisworkbook.sheets(iCnt).range("A1").value = "this is an example on how to use the sheet index"
next iCnt
```

Comment: thanks @kimgysen for the reply. Very clear and this does make sense. I'll keep the hierarchy in mind next time. 

Just a thought. Can you use thisworkbook.activesheet.protect as well? I'm using one sheet as a template to create a new one. This copies the macro. But then I have to rename the sheetname in the macro in the new sheet to make it work in the new sheet.

Comment: It is technically possible, but I will always advise against it. In my experience, using activesheet leads - more often than not - to bugs. Not immediately, but VBA is typically the kind of language that will turn into a mess after a certain time due to people who add and remove code without much thought. Another thing is that I have doubts about your application design. Copying the sheet with VBA seems strange practice; I'm not sure why you would do this. VBA in Sheet modules should only be used for Sheet Events (such as activate, onchange, etc).

Comment: Well, we run statistics in the sheet. Whenever we do a new test, we create a new sheet. But since many employees here don't know excel that well, this mostly results in people changing the sheets, which leads to wrong calculations. Therefore I made it 'dumbo-proof' so they only have to click a button. I agree that it is not ideal, but it's a bit better than always correcting the sheets whenever somebody felt like adding a few things ;)

But i'll remember your advice. Maybe I'll find a workaround or instruct my fellow employees properly.